# Trying to spyOn a response inside a fire-and-forget method with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, pact

I'm working on a project in node.js where I'm setting up contract testing
So  I want to test my API requests and response
here is the method I want to test

```
import rp from 'request-promise';
    
const foo = async () : Promise<void> => { 
      await rp(options).then(resp => {
        return resp;
      })
    }
```

here in my test I want to check the resp (which will be provided by the pact when running the test)
The problem is I do not know how I can capture this variable to check it...
I've tried to use spies with no success and a mock won't help...

```
import requestPromise from "request-promise";

const response = jest.spyOn(requestPromise(options),"then") 

await foo()

expect(response).toReturnWith({test:"test"})
```

I also tried to spyOn requestPromise() "post"
but no results

Is there a way to test this ?

Comment: Is this part of a pact test?

Comment: You cannot spyOn this object because it's not the same object you've used, `requestPromise(options) !== requestPromise(options)`. Mock `request-promise` package, you generally shouldn't do real requests in tests any way.

Comment: thanks for your answer, It's not very clear in my post, but I am doing contract testing with pact.js, in this case pact.js is mocking the provider which will receive the request and send back the expected response. So testing the request is precisely the point of my test
This is different from unit testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to attempt here. You mention Pact but there is no use of it in your example.

Why do you need to spy on the request at all? Just return something from `foo` itself (instead of void) and assert on the response.

If you're using Pact, it will do all of the http request checks for you.  And ensure the request was made.

You then just assert on the response.

Comment: it is part of a pact test, the problem is that the method foo doesn't return the response.
I know that one solution would be to modify the method so that it returns the response but I try avoiding to modify code in production if possible